# Getting Private Channel Info when Linking Public Slack Channel

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am trying to create a link to a public channel in a post message to slack programmatically.

Following the [documentation](https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting#linking-channels), I am posting a slack message containing `<#C...>` with a valid public channel within my slack workspace. However, the display shows only Private channel info, instead of the actual channel.

[image]

Are there additional permissions or setup required?

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work with using `<#{normalized_channel_name}>`